# Where to set Ace editor blockScrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

When I use [ace](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) (with [jquery-ace](https://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/)) to change a textarea to ace-editor, it shows this warning on the console:

```
Automatically scrolling cursor into view after selection change 
this will be disabled in the next version 
set editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity to disable this message
```

Where to set that `editor.$blockScrolling` variable to remove those warnings?

```
var aces = el.find('textarea.code.json');
var aceInit = function() {
 //window.ace.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect
 //$.ace.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect
 //window.jQueryAce.AceDecorator.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect
 //window.jQueryAce.BaseEditor.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect
 //window.jQueryAce.TextAreaEditor.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect
 aces.ace({theme: 'eclipse', lang: 'json'}).each(function (idx, editor) {
  var el = $(editor);
  var editor = el.data('ace').editor;
  //editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect
  var ace = editor.ace;
  //ace.$blockScrolling = Infinity; // no effect, even this the correct one
  ace.setReadOnly(el.prop('disabled'));
  ace.setOption("maxLines", 10);
  ace.setOption("minLines", 2);
 });
}; // this function called when ace.js, mode-json.js and jquery-ace.js loaded
```

Comment: the one with `// no effect, even this the correct one` is the correct one. Maybe something unsets that property later? Could you create a demo showing this issue?

Comment: ah wait, it works now, maybe I forgot to reload the javascript..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct one would be:

```
var el = $(the_element);
var editor = el.data('ace').editor;
editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
```